# How to display data in a tabular format using gocui in Golang?

Tags: go, terminal, console-application, text-rendering

I'm working on a Go project using the gocui library for creating a terminal-based user interface. I have a list of results that I want to display in a tabular format with multiple columns. However, I'm having trouble achieving the desired layout.

I have earlier used termbox-go library and achieved the output using this code:

```
func renderText(row, column int, text string) {
    for i, char := range text {
        termbox.SetCell(column+i, row, char, termbox.ColorDefault, termbox.ColorDefault)
    }
}
```

I have tried doing this with gocui but it didn't work:

```
func renderText(v *gocui.View, row, column int, text string) {
    v.Write([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("\033[%d;%dH%s", row+1, column, text)))
}
```

I am new to golang so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Insufficient information. Your program is not a minimal reproducible example. You didn't tell us which gocui package you're using. You say "didn't work" but should tell us what actually happened. Finally, if you're using https://github.com/jroimartin/gocui why are you hand crafting the ANSI escape sequence to move the cursor? The whole point of using a package like gocui is to avoid having to do that.

Comment: @KurtisRader that's why i am asking how to do that in gocui library since the library is for that purpose. Now I don't know which other package is also known as gocui. Not answering questions is not the way to go. I did not find anything regarding my question in the documentation. If I would've found i would not have asked it here.

Comment: You may want to read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

The documentation has a [MoveCursor](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jroimartin/gocui#View.MoveCursor) method that seems to be what you're looking for.